# perl split but keep special separator with second string

Tags: perl

I have the following string below that I need to split up but I need to keep the separator with the second portion of the string. So that I end up with:

```
$a = 'State of mind is primary';
$b = '\098\455\098evertyhing else is secondary.-Eckhart Tolle '
```

My attempt:

```
my $string = 'State of mind is primary\098\455\098evertyhing else is secondary. -Eckhart Tolle';

my $separator = '\098\455\098';
my ($a, $b) = split($separator, $string);
print "$a\n";
print "$b\n";
```

How can I accomplish this with perl split?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split on the 0-length string that precedes the sequence.

```
my ($x, $y) = split(/(?=\\098\\455\\098)/, $string);
```

Comment: And my goodness, a reputation of 261k? Really? Hats off to you sir. That's incredible -- mind boggling really.

Comment: Yes, excellent contribution as usual.

Answer (score 3):

Use a positive lookahead.

(I've simplified your separator to remove one potential source of confusion)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $string = 'State of mind is primaryXXXevertyhing else is secondary. -Eckhart Tolle';
my $separator = 'XXX';

my ($first, $second) = split /(?=$separator)/, $string;

say "$first / $second";
```

And the output:

```
$ perl split
State of mind is primary / XXXevertyhing else is secondary. -Eckhart Tolle
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `split()` use pattern matching.

**EDIT** I guess you really meant `\` not octal characters:

```
my $string = "State of mind is primary\\098\\455\\098\everything else is secondary. -Eckhart Tolle";
my($a, $b) = ($string =~ /^(.+)(\\098\\455\\098.+)$/);
print "A: '$a'\n";
print "B: '$b'\n";
```

output:

```
A: 'State of mind is primary'
B: '\098\455\098ertyhing else is secondary. -Eckhart Tolle'
```

Comment: Apparently, due to the nature of the separator, I get the following errors.

'\09' resolved to '\o{0}9' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.+)(\09 <-- HERE 8\455\098.+)$/ at test_split.pl line 5.
'\09' resolved to '\o{0}9' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.+)(\098\455\09 <-- HERE 8.+)$/ at test_split.pl line 5.

Comment: I really do mean 'octal characters' the strings will have a slash with three digits.

Comment: @gatorreina `\455` is not a valid octal character. The maximum is `\o{277}`. I guess you might want to encode Unicode characters. that would be `\u{...}`